# How to configure environment variables in Hashicorp Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm quite new to Terraform, though I have gone through all of the instructional modules available on Hashicorp's site.

Currently, I'm struggling with understanding how to set up environment variables. I know how to reference variables in the main.tf config (`access_key = "${var.access_key}"`), and I know how to save that access key to a separate file and reference that, but what I don't understand (and can't find any documentation/instruction on) is how to set up environment variables so I don't have to save the access key to a file.

Does anyone know how best to go about doing this?

Answer (score 20):

Terraform can infer the following environment variables for AWS

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="anaccesskey"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="asecretkey"
```

Ref: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/#environment-variables

But I would suggest trying the `AWS Profile`.
You can add credentials to `~/.aws/credentials` file like

```
[myprofile]
aws_access_key_id     = anaccesskey
aws_secret_access_key = asecretkey
```

and then you can set environment variable `export AWS_PROFILE=myprofile`. Now, if you run terraform from this shell, it should pick credentials listed under `myprofile`.

Also, you can have you `AWS Provider` code as follows:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "myprofile"
  region  = "${var.region}"
}
```

In my experience, interacting with AWS using `profile` is easy and better than setting environment variables on each shell.

You can refer an example here https://github.com/pradeepbhadani/tf-examples/blob/master/ex2/provider.tf

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for providing these suggestions. I am trying to get this working in Azure though, just as a proof of concept. I might take a look at AWS Vault at some point in the future.

Answer (score 11):

Some providers all you to set provider credentials/configuration via environment variables directly. For example, in the case of the AWS provider you can use the [AWS SDK environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) as mentioned in the [AWS provider documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/#environment-variables):

> You can provide your credentials via the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, environment variables, representing your AWS Access Key and AWS Secret Key, respectively.

With example usage shown as:

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="anaccesskey"
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="asecretkey"
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-west-2"
$ terraform plan
```

For the [Azure provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/) most of the provider config can be set by environment variables without needing to be defined in the provider configuration:

```
$ export ARM_CLIENT_ID="aclientid"
$ export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="asubscriptionid"
$ export ARM_TENANT_ID="atenantid"
$ terraform plan
```

In the more general case, Terraform will automatically load any defined variables that are prefixed with [`TF_VAR_`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html#tf_var_name).

So if you have something like this:

```
variable "foo" {}
```

You can set the value by exporting the `TF_VAR_foo` environment variable:

```
export TF_VAR_foo=bar
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! 

Just to provide a bit more detail, I am using the AzureRM Provider, and for reference, here is some of my main.tf configuration:

provider "azurerm" {
    version     = "=1.20.0"
 access_key  = "${var.access_key}"
 region      = "${var.region}"
}

This is my variables.tf config file:

variable "access_key" {}
variable "region" {
  default = "eastus"
  }

I... guess I am still uncertain how to go about assigning my access key to the ${var.access_key} variable. I must be missing something. Sorry for being dense!

Comment: Also apologies, not sure how to get formatting to cooperate for these comments!

Comment: The Azure provider doesn't take an `access_key` parameter. It's probably worth reading the [AzureRM provider docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/) quickly to get a better understanding of how to use it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Perhaps I am actually phrasing my question incorrectly. So, reference this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/terraform/terraform-backend), that is basically what I am trying to do. I'm just trying to get the Azure Storage account access key stored in Azure Key Vault, and I am not able to get the export ARM_ACCESS_KEY=<storage access key> command to run correctly.

Comment: It seems like you're doing two different things. Remove any reference to 'access_key' from your tf files and then try running `export ARM_ACCESS_KEY=<your key>` before `tf plan`

Comment: So, I tried that out, but I am unable to run the export export ARM_ACCESS_KEY=<your key> command. It says 'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Any ideas on how to get this to cooperate?

Comment: If you do not have the `export` command then you're probably on Windows which means you need to use the `set` command. The full command you want to use is `set ARM_ACCESS_KEY="<yourkey>"` on `cmd` prompt or `$env:ARM_ACCESS_KEY="<yourkey>"` https://www.shellhacks.com/windows-set-environment-variable-cmd-powershell/

Answer (score 3):

1. when I started learning tf, I have used a `terraform.tfvars` file where in I put:

```
aws_access_key="myaccesskey"
aws_secret_key="mysecertkey"
region='aws-region'
```

in `main.tf`:

```
variable "aws_access_key" {}
variable "aws_secret_key" {}
variable "private_key_path" {}

provider "aws" {
  access_key = var.aws_access_key
  secret_key = var.aws_secret_key
  region     = var.region
}
```

making sure, both files in the same dir.

2. then I started using env varibles in Mac:

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
$ terraform plan
```

3. using profile, `~/.aws/credentials`

```
aws configure
AWS Access Key ID: yourID
AWS Secret Access Key: yourSecert
Default region name : aws-region
Default output format : env
```

I hope it helps!

good luck, terraform is an amazing thing to learn!

Answer (score 1):

The Terraform way of using environment variables and thus arbitrary values for all good things Terraform are by prefixing *any* **environment** variable with `TF_VAR_` and then Terraform will automagically use it.

For your specific use case this would mean, that you can set the **Terraform** variable `access_key` by setting the **environment* variable `TF_VAR_access_key`.

This technique is built-in into Terraform itself and is thus independent from any specific provider.

Documentation can be found at https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html#tf_var_name it works also for *older* Terraform version (I've tested it with 0.11).